# Поиск ближайших клиентов

Tags: python

Помогите, пожалуйста. Есть массив `{clientObject:[позиция x, позиция y]}`. В нем таких "клиентов" очень много. Есть другой клиент, которому нужно найти 5 самых ближайших клиентов к нему по x и y.

Comment: Сформировать массив (список?) расстояний до клиента, отсортировать по расстоянию и взять пять первых

Comment: Линейный поиск не устраивает?

Comment: @dzhioev только с приоритетной очередью из пяти искомых элементов. Но это писать надо. А сортировка -- 

      c = map (lambda i: ((clientObject[i][0] - 1)**2 + (clientObject[i][1] - 1)**2, i), xrange(0, len(clientObject)))
      c.sort()

Правда я не обратил внимание на синтаксис в задании, если там dictionary, то выглядеть будет чуть иначе

Comment: @alexlz, это был вопрос к ТС. Просто возможно линейная сложность в его задаче недопустима, не зря же он пишет про то, что клиентов очень много. В таком случае надо смотреть в сторону чего-то вроде R-tree. А о простой сортировке я даже не подумал. =)

Comment: @dzhioev, не всегда линейная сложность это немного. Что если надо тысячи/миллионы запросов в секунду поддерживать?

Comment: @dzhioev Харакири. Или куча процессоров/ядер. Вот если миллионы "клиентов", да ещё на питоне -- тогда просто харакири.

Comment: Если записей и правда _очень_ много, лучше их для начала кластеризовать: разбить на квадраты. Для данной записи искать записи-кандидаты нужно лишь в её квадрате и в соседних — такой себе аналог хеширования. Размеры квадратов для разбиения подбирайте в соответствии со здравым смыслом и логикой задачи.

Comment: @VladD мне нравится. Координаты: 

     (0, 0), (10, 0), (20, 0), (30, 0), (0, 10), (0, 20), (0, 30), (11,11), (11, 12), (11, 13), (12, 11), (70, 0), (0, 70) для узла (75, 75).

Чудесно разбивается на 64 квадрата со стороной 10.

@dzhioev препроцессинг? Какой?

Comment: @alexlz, я же писал, что можно R-tree создать, например. Про R-tree пишу, потому что сталкивался по работе с ним, и задача была похожая -- найти несколько точек, ближайших к заданной. Сложность поиска в R-tree -- логарифмическая.

Answer (score 1):

Вам поможет [теория графов](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B2).

Когда вникнете, можете или написать свою реализацию алгоритма либо поискать готовую.

Comment: И теория алгоритмов, и несколько книг по программированию вообще  и по программированию на питоне...

Comment: Отличный совет!

Answer (score 1):

Выгрузите всё в [`mongodb`](http://www.mongodb.org/) - там можно-создать гео-индекс и искать ближайшие по координатам объекты.